# Not able to execute (.jnlp) file directly from download - Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, permissions, java

We have an analysis pipeline which we retrieve the data from our own server and run the analysis on a web-browser based software interface (java-based). That involves 3 simple steps:
1. Download the data file (.jnlp);
2. Click on the file (from the Download menu bar); and
3. Select "Open with".

In this case, the file should be opened with "OpenJDK Java8".
Whenever I select that option, I get the following message:

`The file '[filename.jnlp]' is not marked as executable.  If this was downloaded or copied from an untrusted source, it may be dangerous to run.  For more details, read about the executable bit.`

I am new to Linux, and from what I have been reading, it seems that it is a problem of setting the permissions. And I also came across [OpenJDk Java Policy Tool](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/wstep1.html), but I can't get to make it work (likely setting the wrong arguments).
Is that in fact the right place to look at? But more importantly: how can I get across this issue?

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Ubuntu, you should be able to right click on the file, select properties, Permissions tab and tick "Allow executing as a program" (or something like that - I'm not in front of an Ubuntu device right now.

For any other distro of Linux, there should be similar GUI options, but I don't know the GUI for any other distribution very well, but you can use the `chmod` command:

```bsh
chmod u+x file
```

Comment: Ah, I assumed you had that installed already. Yes, .jlnp files are for IcedTea Web

Comment: Thanks, @DCowan. I was able to do that by "manually" changing the permission of the files. I was looking for more of an automated solution. But now I found it, by installing the icedtea plugin. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve it by installing and running the downloaded file on [icedtea-8-plugin](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/icedtea-8-plugin).